# Android apklib content gets reported by Findbugs

Tags: android, findbugs, apklib

i have a dependency to an APK Lib in my Maven Project, Findbugs reports errors for example in the generated R class. 
How can i exclude this ? I already have an exclude file for the project with basicly ignore the R file already, but the APK File gets inflated and seems to be handled different.

Thanks